# Houseguest lies about seeing ghost

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I found this in a short story compilation in the early 90's.

A woman is a guest at a manor, and persuaded to sleep in a ballroom. Every night she sees a ghastly phantom of a woman appear, but afraid people will think she's crazy, lies about her nights being uneventful. This comes back to haunt her (and everyone else really) when her hosts throw a celebration in the ballroom, and the ghost the woman saw shows up.

It turns out the ghost, in life, was murdered in the ballroom long ago, and her spirit warned she would seek revenge if it was ever again "used for a joyous purpose". The houseguest's hosts tell her they had her sleep in the ballroom to see if the story of the murder and the haunting was true; after hearing her repeated denial they decided there was no ghost and had the ill-fated party.

At the end the houseguest flees the manor shortly before it burns down (I think we're supposed to assume that's the spirit's doing).